# How to get location information in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get location information by using `Geolocation API` in react.

I made a `button` to get location info in this code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      latitude: null,
      longitude: null,
    }
  }

  position = async () => {
    await navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => this.setState({ 
        latitude: position.coords.latitude, 
        longitude: position.coords.longitude
      }), 
      err => console.log(err)
    );
    console.log(this.state.latitude)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.position} className='Filter'>Filter</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Once I pressed a `button`, console shows `null`.
However, when I pressed a `button` again, the console shows location info.

Do you have any idea why I couldn't get the location info for the first time?

Comment: try console.log inside the render not in that function

Comment: It will still give a null and not update the component.

Comment: setState has a second argument, a callback , that is triggered after state is set, so put console.log inside it like .setState({...}, function(){console.log(this.state.latitude)});

Comment: @HabeebRahman Thank you for your comment. that worked !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`setState` is an asynchronous function.

When you call `position` the first time, the state is eventually updated. The second time it is already there, which is why it gets logged.

You can move the logging to the second parameter of `setState`, which is a callback.

```
this.setState({ 
    latitude: position.coords.latitude, 
    longitude: position.coords.longitude
  }, newState => console.log(newState))
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I put `setState` in `componentWillMount`, and I could solve it!!

Comment: @gnxvw You could just `await` the `setState` call, assuming you declare the `getCurrentPosition` callback as `async`.